# Display number of options selected by the filter menu

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an app with a filter menu based on options that the user can select. What is the best way for displaying the number of option selected inside the toolbar?

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVuP7.png)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using `CheckBox`s for your filters since you didn't post any code. Here is the generic `OnClickListener` that you would want to use for each `CheckBox`

```
int numChecked = 0;

checkbox.setOnCheckedChangedListener(new OnCheckedChangedListener(){
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChange(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
          if(isChecked) numChecked++;
          else numChecked--;
          //insert code for what should happen on filter click
     }

//do this for all of your checkboxes
textView.setText("filter(" + String.valueOf(numChecked) + ")");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
The filters menu is a mix of options, not just checkboxes.
I haven't post the code because I haven't started yet seen that I am not fully sure about all the type of options that I have. 
By the way, you give me a very good hint. Thank you for your time